# Checking if an input is an int after slicing a str

Tags: python, string, if-statement, integer

I'm working on a homework assignment (honestly been working for a while now) where we take input from the user, slice the string, and store the new strings in two different variables. The second part of the split string is supposed to be a number and I'm attempting to write an if statement to check if it is indeed a number. The problem is it's not because I split a string, so it's defined as a str. I know I could redefine the variable to an int() but that would produce an error if they weren't to enter an integer. Sorry if this isn't clear, this is my first question! (I can also post a screenshot of the instructions if that would be more helpful, I just don't know if that's encouraged on here.)

```
data_title = input("Enter a title for the data: ")
print("You entered: ", data_title)

column1 = input("Enter the column 1 header: ")
print("You entered: ", column1)

column2 = input("Enter the column 2 header: ")
print("You entered: ", column2)

data_point = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input): ")



while data_point != -1:
if ',' in data_point:
    if data_point.count(',') < 2:
        data_split = data_point.split(",")
        data_stg = data_split[0]
        data_int = data_split[1]
        if data_split[1].isdigit() is True:
            print("Data string: ", data_stg)
            print("Data integer: ", data_int)
            data_point = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input): ")
        else:
            print("Error: Comma not followed by an integer.")
            data_point = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input): ")
    else:
        print("Error: Too many commas in input.")
        data_point = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input): ")
else:
    print("Error: No comma in string.")
    data_point = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input): ")
```

The problem is in the in the 3rd if loop nested in the while loop. I have to make sure their input has an integer after the comma.

```
 if data_split[1].isdigit() is True:
                print("Data string: ", data_stg)
                print("Data integer: ", data_int)
                data_point = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input): ")
            else:
                print("Error: Comma not followed by an integer.")
                data_point = input("Enter a data point (-1 to stop input): ")
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not [as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you give me the captured image, I couldn't see the full requests.
So I made an example for you.

```
while True:
  a = input('please give me your data :')
  if ',' not in a:
    try:
       if int(a) == -1: break
    except:
      pass
      
    print( 'please give me the seperated inputs wiht ","')
  else:
    b, c = a.split(',')
    try:
      c = int(c)
    except:
      print( 'please give me int !!')
    else:
      print( b, c)
```

I believe this code would help you see what python is.

Comment: sorry as I said this is my first question. I didn't notice how to post the code before. I'm working on formatting it in the question and will update the question soon. Thank you for the response though, I will try your method after updating my question